# how can i send get and post request from esp01 using arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, http, web

I am using an esp8266 01 module with the Arduino Uno to establish a communication between the Arduino and my web site. I actually don't know how to send Rest HTTP requests from the Arduino to get data from my web site. I have done research but all I got is codes using `nodemcu` so I was wondering will the code of nodeMCU work fine on the Arduino using ESP01 and if not then how can I send get and post request from the Arduino using esp01
this the code that I found

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid = "SERVER NAME";
const char* password = "SERVER PASSWORD";

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting...");
  }
}

void loop() 
{
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    HTTPClient http; //Object of class HTTPClient
    http.begin("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1");
    int httpCode = http.GET();

    if (httpCode > 0) 
    {
      const size_t bufferSize = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(2) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(3) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(5) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(8) + 370;
      DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(bufferSize);
      JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(http.getString());

      int id = root["id"]; 
      const char* name = root["name"]; 
      const char* username = root["username"]; 
      const char* email = root["email"]; 

      Serial.print("Name:");
      Serial.println(name);
      Serial.print("Username:");
      Serial.println(username);
      Serial.print("Email:");
      Serial.println(email);
    }
    http.end(); //Close connection
  }
  delay(60000);
}
```

Comment: use the WiFiEsp library

Comment: can you tell me what this library can offer to me

Comment: it works on Arduino over esp8266 AT commands with standard Arduino networking API used in the sketch you added to the question

Comment: can you tell me how can I use it

Comment: wire the esp-01 to the same way as sketches witch use the AT commands. install the WiFiEsp library in Library Manager and see the examples

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: i tried what you sid but when i run the code i code a lot of ??????? what does that means

Comment: it could be wrong baud rate. does the baud rate in sketch match the baud rate of the AT firmware? you should use 9600 baud

Comment: i changed it to 9600 but now i got [WiFiEsp] Initializing ESP module
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] Warning: Unsupported firmware

Comment: send `AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0` to AT firmware. it will change the default baud rate

Comment: what AT firmware version do you have? it reports unsupported for the latest AT firmware. you can ignore it then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95124/discussion-between-ela-hidri-and-juraj).